# how do I render code in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP.NET and I have no clue how to get around it, I've been working on projects where Webforms have been mostly used, and I have some amount of knowledge of how to use various stuff.

But I'm stuck with this :

```
<%= Corina.Corina.Render<ContentPage>(x => x.Description) %>
```

How do I render this in MVC ?

I tried this :

```
@{
    Corina.Corina.Render<ContentPage>(x => x.Description);
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What view engine? How do pass the string to the view?

Comment: create an ActionResult and return View(model)

Comment: No I am really confused. Is that the string you want to output, or is this an object?

Comment: It's a string actually

Comment: You want to output the string `"Corina.Corina.Render<ContentPage>(x => x.Description);"`, not simply get `x.Description` on to the page?

Comment: Yes, what that object return in webforms it's simply a string ( or html in case it has any html tags, but still a string )

Comment: So, you want to get the value of `x.Description` on the page. Not have  `"Corina.Corina.Render<ContentPage>(x => x.Description);"` displayed to the browser. The question is phrased in a confusing way and you are really not clarifying.

Comment: Now, you said what you tried but not what happened. Can you share those details? Errors or exceptions?

Comment: Sorry @Oded, I haven't worked with ASP a lot .... but what you just said makes sense, as I'm trying to grab property `Description` from that object ( it grabs it from a RavenDB database that runs locally on my machine ) ... I'm just trying to make it work in MVC as it does in webforms ...

Comment: I just don't get anything, no exception, no errors. I tried @KirillBestemyanov answer before I posted my question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what is your problem, you need to change your code to razor. You can do it.
Your code in aspx engine:

```
<%= Corina.Corina.Render<ContentPage>(x => x.Description) %>
```

has equivalent in razor:

```
@(Corina.Corina.Render<ContentPage>(x => x.Description))
```

Comment: Are you sure `Description` is not empty?

Comment: Actually now it works ... seems like it was cached or something, because after the fifth forced refresh I got the string I was expecting ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

for .aspx view

```
<%= Model.Description %>
```

for rager view

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Description)
```

Hope this will help !!